# Download a file in python with urllib2 instead of urllib

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I'm trying to download a tarball file and save it locally with python. With urllib it's pretty simple:

```
import urllib    

urllib2.urlopen(url, 'compressed_file.tar.gz')
tar = tarfile.open('compressed_file.tar.gz')
print tar.getmembers()
```

So my question is really simple: What's the way to achieve this using the urllib2 library?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is the example you posted supposed to be working or broken code? You've imported `urllib` but are using `urllib2`. Also if you're open to it, `requests` is a really nice library for dealing with these sorts of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

> `urllib2.urlopen(url[, data[, timeout[, cafile[, capath[, cadefault[,
>   context]]]]])` 
>   Open the URL url, which can be either a string or a
>   Request object.
>
> *`data` may be a string specifying additional data to send to the server, or `None` if no such data is needed.*

Nothing in `urlopen` interface documentation says, that second argument is a name of file where response should be written.

You need to explicitly write data read from response to file:

```
r = urllib2.urlopen(url)
CHUNK_SIZE = 1 << 20
with open('compressed_file.tar.gz', 'wb') as f:
    # line belows downloads all file at once to memory, and dumps it to file afterwards
    # f.write(r.read())
    # below is preferable lazy solution - download and write data in chunks
    while True:
        chunk = r.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
        if not chunk:
            break
        f.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Works great thanks! Just one silly question but I'm new in python so bare with me. What's this syntax 1 << 20. I mean what does it mean?

Comment: @JimVer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work